# Continuous approximation of upper semicontinuous indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let us define the upper semicontinuous indicator function as $$I(x) \triangleq \begin{cases} 1, & \quad x \geq 0 \\ 0, & \quad x<0. \end{cases}$$

I need to find some (at least one) continuously differentiable approximation functions $L(x,\nu)$ such that, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $\lim_{\nu \to \infty} L(x,\nu) = I(x)$.

Hint: I've tried with the logistic function $$L(x,\nu) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\nu x)}$$ but its limit is given by $$\lim_{\nu \to \infty} L(x,\nu) = \begin{cases} 1, & \quad x > 0 \\ 1/2, & \quad x=0 \\ 0, & \quad x<0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: You can simply define $I(0) = 1/2$

Comment: For my problem, I need $I(0)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small translation of the logistic function helps. Let

$$A(x,\nu) = L\left(x + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}},\nu\right).$$

For $x\geqslant 0$, we have

$$A(x,\nu) = \frac{1}{1+\exp\left(-\nu\left(x+\nu^{-1/2}\right)\right)} \geqslant \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\sqrt{\nu})} \to 1,$$

and for $x < 0$, we have

$$A(x,\nu) \leqslant \frac{1}{1+\exp(\nu\lvert x\rvert - \sqrt{\nu})} \to 0$$

since $\nu\lvert x\rvert$ grows faster than $\sqrt{\nu}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then, there will be still a point, say $\hat{x}$, for which $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} L(\hat{x},\alpha)=1/2$, right?

Comment: No. The amount by which the functions are translated tends to $0$, so the problematic part is sandwiched in the region $-2/\sqrt{\nu} < x < 0$, which vanishes in the limit. The estimates show that $A(x,\nu) \to 1$ for $x\geqslant 0$ and $A(x,\nu) \to 0$ for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is to smear $I(x)$ with some smooth non-negative function
$\rho _{a}(x)$ which converges to the $\delta $-function as $a\rightarrow 0$
. For instance a suitably scaled Gaussian.
\begin{equation*}
I_{a}(x)=\int dy\rho _{a}(x-y)I(y)
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\int dxf(x)I_{a}(x)\rightarrow \int dxf(x)I(x)
\end{equation*}
for a suitable set of smooth $f(x)$.